# Error coming up almost everytime I run my aplication from VS

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Please see the pic. and advise why this error is coming up and how to fix it.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Most probably 'Me.Name' may not be accepting 'string'. Can you be more precise about the error.

Comment: Try clean and rebuild.  The name of the form shouldn't be giving that error.

Comment: did several times ! did not work

Comment: I can repro this by adding, say, a button to the form and naming it "Name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your datagrid column's name from "Name" to "colName". Me.Name is a property, so naming it "Name" is causing problems. This is one reason I like to use a type prefix (btn, txt, lbl, etc) to signify control type.